# Forking in GitHub

Tags: github

I have a private repository in github that has 5 collaborators.Now when the collaborators try to fork the repository, they get a page saying "Hardcore Forking Action". It stays in the same page for a very long time. Even one day after the initial fork, when the collaborator visits his/her forked repository page, it says the same thing.Is this error or I have to do something else in addition to adding collaborators to the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an error. Report it to [Github support](http://support.github.com/) - They're very helpful.